# Convergence of supremum norms

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying the difference between pointwise and uniform convergence for sequences of continuous functions.

Is it true that if $f_{n} \to f$ pointwise, then $ \|f_{n}\|_{\infty} \to \|f\|_{\infty}$?

It seems true when they converge uniformly, but I can't find a counterexample if the convergence is only pointwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the functions $f_n : [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ given by $f_n (x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0, & x \in [0, n] \\ 1, & x > n \end{matrix} \right.$. Then $f_n \to 0$, but $\sup f_n = 1 \not\to 0$.

If you want your functions to also be continuous, consider $g_n : [0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ given by $g_n (x) = x^n$. Then $g_n \to 0$, but $\sup g_n = 1 \not\to 0$.

Comment: In your first example, actually $f_n\to 1$

Comment: @user160738: Thank you, I meant the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try with $f_n=$ a function that is zero except in a very narrow and tall spike, narrower and taller with $n$.